# Retrieving last quarter's dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

**Background**
I am trying to inject a payload with the dates for the most recent prior fiscal quarter.

**Example**
If today is April 20th (which is a date in Q2), the most recently completed prior quarter would be Q1 (i.e., January 1 - March 31), and therefore I would inject the payload with *`start_date: 2022-12-31` and `end_date: 2023-03-31`. 
***Note** that the `start_date` should always be the date prior to the beginning of a quarter; this is normal practice.

**Current Code**

```
# I am currently injecting the current dates into my payload.
# Instead, I am looking for the previous quarter's dates
start_date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    
    def job_initializer():
        #   calling function that returns variables required for API call
        key, secret, url = authentication()
        payload = """
        {
          "data":{
            "type":"jobs",
            "attributes":{
              "job_type":"portfolio_view_results",
              "parameters":{
                "view_id":"416555",
                "portfolio_type":"firm",
                "portfolio_id":"1",
                "output_type":"csv",
                "start_date":"%s",
                "end_date":"%s"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        """ % (start_date, end_date)
```

**Suggestions**
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might achieve this? I see a lot of historical posts from 10yrs ago, however I am hoping this can be achieved using `pandas` or another time-focused python library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the start dates of the quarters as `datetime` objects like [Mark shows in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76068662/843953), you can hardcode them as tuples that specify the year offset, the month, and the day.

```
import datetime as dt

quarters = [(-1, 12, 31), (0, 3, 31), (0, 6, 30), (0, 9, 30), (0, 12, 31)]
```

Given `today = dt.date.today()`,
the index of the start date of the current quarter in that list is just `(today.month - 1 // 3)`. The index of the end date is one plus the start date index:

```
i_start = (today.month - 1) // 3

q_start = dt.datetime(today.year - quarters[i_start][0], *quarters[i_start][1:])
# datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 31, 0, 0)

q_end = dt.datetime(today.year - quarters[i_start + 1][0], *quarters[i_start + 1][1:])
# datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 30, 0, 0)
```

---

To use this approach in a pandas dataframe (`df`) that contains datetime objects in the column `df["Date"]`, recall that pandas offers a [`Series.dt.quarter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) that gives `i_start + 1` for any date. Let's modify `quarters` so that we can use it in pandas vector functions:

```
quarters_df = pd.DataFrame(quarters, columns=["year_offset", "month", "day"])
```

`quarters_df` looks like this:

```
   year_offset  month  day
0           -1     12   31
1            0      3   31
2            0      6   30
3            0      9   30
4            0     12   31
```

Then, you can do:

```
# Get the index of the quarter start and end date
i_end = df['Date'].dt.quarter
i_start = i_end - 1

# Get those elements from quarters_df, then reset the index to the original dataframe's index
q_start = quarters_df.loc[i_start].set_index(df.index)
# Set year to the date's year plus the year offset
q_start["year"] = q_start["year_offset"] + df["Date"].dt.year

q_end = quarters_df.loc[i_end].set_index(df.index)
q_end["year"] = q_end["year_offset"] + df["Date"].dt.year
```

---

**Note:** You could also use the same formula above to get `i_start` and `i_end`, but we have `dt.quarter` so why not use it :)

```
i_start = (df["Date"].dt.month - 1) // 3
i_end = i_start + 1
```

---

And finally, build the column of datetimes:

```
df["quarter_start"] = pd.to_datetime(q_start[["year", "month", "day"]])

df["quarter_end"] = pd.to_datetime(q_end[["year", "month", "day"]])
```

For the following example dataframe:

```
data = [dt.datetime(2003, 6, 4, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2000, 10, 9, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2023, 11, 23, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2011, 2, 7, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2009, 7, 27, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2005, 12, 23, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2019, 9, 28, 0, 0),
 dt.datetime(2004, 2, 21, 0, 0)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date'])
```

The approach shown above gives us:

```
        Date quarter_start quarter_end
0 2003-06-04    2003-03-31  2003-06-30
1 2015-06-22    2015-03-31  2015-06-30
2 2000-10-09    2000-09-30  2000-12-31
3 2023-11-23    2023-09-30  2023-12-31
4 2011-02-07    2010-12-31  2011-03-31
5 2009-07-27    2009-06-30  2009-09-30
6 2005-12-23    2005-09-30  2005-12-31
7 2018-02-04    2017-12-31  2018-03-31
8 2019-09-28    2019-06-30  2019-09-30
9 2004-02-21    2003-12-31  2004-03-31
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be something built into numpy or some other library, but since there are only four quarters, it's not much to hard-code:

```
import datetime
 
today = datetime.date.today()
quarters = [ datetime.date(today.year-1,12,31),
             datetime.date(today.year,3,31),
             datetime.date(today.year,6,30),
             datetime.date(today.year,9,30),
             datetime.date(today.year,12,31) ]
quarter, start_date = [(i,d) for i,d in enumerate(quarters) if d < today][-1]
end_date = quarters[quarter+1]
print(f'{start_date}, {end_date}')
```